# How does the inner function get the 'dispatch' parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React-Redux!

But I have a problem.

How does the inner function (`async dispatch`) receive the `dispatch()` parameter?

`GetCurrentUserInfo` Action Creator function:

```
export const getCurrentUserInfo = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get('/api/users/me')

  dispatch({
    type: userActions.SET_CURRENT_USER_INFO,
    users: response.data.data
  })

  return response.data.data
}
```

How `getCurrentUserInfo` is called:

```
export const AuthGuard = connect(
  state => ({
    currentUserSlug: state.session.currentUser
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    authOrRedirect: () => {
      return dispatch(getCurrentUserInfo()).catch(() => {
        history.replace('/login')
      })
    }
  })
)(AuthGuardComponent)
```

`getCurrentUserInfo()` does not receive any parameters, but is it because it is enclosed in  `dispatch(getCurrentUserInfo())`?

Answer (score 0):

`getCurrentUserInfo()` returns a function that expects one parameter `dispatch`. You need to call that returned function and pass the `dispatch` parameter to it:

```
export const AuthGuard = connect(
  state => ({}),
  dispatch => ({
    authOrRedirect: () => {
      return getCurrentUserInfo()(dispatch).catch(() => {
        history.replace('/login')
      })
    }
  })
)(AuthGuardComponent)
```

#### For example:

Obviously you could write the `getCurrentUserInfo()` like this:

```
const getCurrentUserInfo = function(){  // create getCurrentUserInfo dispatcher
  return async function(dispatch){
    // ...
  };
}
```

The dispatchProp could be written like this:

```
export const AuthGuard = connect(
  state => ({}),
  dispatch => ({
    authOrRedirect: () => {
      const getUserInfoDispatcher = getCurrentUserInfo();  // create dispatcher
      getUserInfoDispatcher(dispatch).catch(() => {        // call dispatcher
        history.replace('/login')
      })
    }
  })
)(AuthGuardComponent)
```

#### common patterns

obviously you are confused about these two patterns, which you might have seen somewhere:

- A: `getCurrentUserInfo()(dispatch)`: call a "dispatching function"
- B: `dispatch(getCurrentUserInfo())`: dispatch an "action"

(**A**) works in your case, because `getCurrentUserInfo()` returns a "dispatching function" *(not an official term)*, i.e. a function that calls `dispatch( someAction )`.
`getCurrentUserInfo()(dispatch)` invokes this "dispatching function".

(**B**) is a pattern that would be used if `getCurrentUserInfo()` would be an "action creator" (which it isn't in your case), i.e. a function that returns an "action", like `{ type: ..., users: ... }`.

Comment: I see, thanks, btw is `dispatch(getCurrentUserInfo())` and `getCurrentUserInfo()(dispatch)` the same?

Comment: no. I updated my answer to explain these two patterns.

Comment: hi, the code I posted is from: `https://github.com/huwcarwyn/react-laravel-boilerplate/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/AuthGuard/AuthGuard.jsx`, and it is written like this default:
` return dispatch(getCurrentUserInfo()).catch(() => {
        history.replace('/login')
      })`
is that a typographical error?